# Bluetooth Gatt Characteristics for Light Level

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, gatt

Does there exist a characteristic for light levels measured by a photoresistor? I cannot seem to find it in the bluetooth specifications, even though I imagined it would be under environmental sensing?
Is there any way to use it anyway without choosing a different characteristic?
https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx

Is it possible to create a custom characteristic for use with light level? Or does it already exist somehow?

I am using an Arduino 101 and I'm reading using BLE on Android.

Comment: I did not find anything useful, but Irradiance. "light level" is not a proper term btw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can can create a Custom GATT service and use it to transfer the value you want. You should use unused 128 bit UUIDs as custom UUIDs. Since this new UUID you created is not supported by Bluetooth, you have to take care of decoding this UUID from the other device to which you are sending date.